Is there an Apple Silicon compatibility filter on Steam for Mac OS?
If you install Steam on Mac OS you can filter by Mac OS compatibility, but sadly this doesn't mean Apple Silicon compatibility, so it's quite useless.
I know there are ways to run certain games that aren't officially compatible with Apple Silicon on those chips, but that doesn't, by far, work for all games, so that's why an official compatibility filter would be really handy.

Perhaps at least a workaround is this list: https://store.steampowered.com/curator/42335871-Playing-Games-on-%25EF%25A3%25BF-Silicon/ supposedly the creator of it only puts games that they have tested themselves.

Yeah, this is a curator kind of thing, and it'll take a while before Valve adds any UI change for that. There may be games that explicitly list support (or lack of) for M1+, but it'll require digging.
